# How to determine how many threads are being used by IIS with wfastcgi?

Tags: python, fastcgi, iis-8.5

I have setup Python [Bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) web application on IIS using [wfastcgi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wfastcgi).

All works fine, but I am trying to understand how multi-threading works.

I did a bit of testing, and I fount out IIS starts several bottle applications (as opposed to calling the same one multiple times) when there are too many request to handle on a single app synchronously.

Do how know how I can see how many applications maximum IIS is allowed to start? and if there is somewhere I can monitor how many are actually running?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to test and configure this?